# 404 Error: provide index.html file with GitHub Pages

Tags: html, web, github, http-status-code-404, hugo

I believe my current problem is that GitHub Pages is unaware that my index.html files are located in the public directory of my master folder. I can't change the directory from the master to the public folder (it's not an available option anymore). I have included some screenshots of my issues. Any idea how to fix this? Here is my Github repository as well anp12/anp12.github.io Thank you very much in advance! 
[image: 404 Error]
[image: index.html in public folder]

Answer (score 4):

You have your index file in the wrong directory. Your master branch needs to have index.html on its root folder.

Checkout how I have done it here:

https://github.com/prateekkarki/prateekkarki.github.io

[Website](https://prateekkarki.github.io)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This worked and helped me publish the website. Now a new issue has occurred with my theme. This is the Hugo-Academic template and I'm assuming there's either something wrong with me using the ".nojekyll" file to workaround other publishing issues I've had or the html document. If you have any insight on that end, it would be greatly appreciated, but I can't thank you enough for helping with the current issue! This is what the site looks like now anp12.github.io

Comment: I don't have much idea with jekyll, not sure if github pages accepts it. But If you moved your files from public folder to root folder, that should do the trick, I think  specially css, js and img folder must be in the root folder for your case

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)